# Creating hierarchy in nested IF statements in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested, hierarchy

In my single Excel worksheet, I have a column of asset titles (Column C) that I am comparing to a named range of asset categories based on a named range of asset keywords using the following formula:

**{ =IFNA(INDEX(categories, MATCH(TRUE, ISNUMBER(SEARCH(keywords, C2
)), 0)), "Other")}**

The formula works fine UNTIL one of the asset titles fits into more than one category. For example, an asset might be both a demonstration and a video.

Where an asset fulfills multiple categories, I know which one I'd prefer. (For example, my asset that is both a video and a demonstration should go in the "Demonstration" category.)

What I can't seem to figure out is how to express this preference in my formula. I tried creating my named range in my order of preference, but this didn't seem to solve the problem. (And, in some instances, that order isn't constant.) Would appreciate any suggestions.

**I AM ON A MAC, so please NO VBA.**  Thank you!

Comment: it should return in order of your list in Keywords.  Match will return the first found in that list.  Order that list.

Comment: Hey Scott - thank you. I did order the "Categories" named range, but that didn't seem create the hierarchy I need in the data returned. But, I also have named ranges for asset topics, which were not ordered. Ordering that seems to help. Still worried about instances where there might be deviation from the list order, but will go with this for now. Thanks again.